# How to check if a layer exists in a geodatabase through ArcToolBox or Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

I have got a python to update a file geodatabase (*.gdb).

Every time the code executes, it needs to check if a certain layer has been already there in the previous geodatabase; if so, delete it and create a new one; otherwise, overwrite it with a new one.

I am just wondering if I can achieve this by ArcToolBox or a python code?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Can we see your code so far?  What you describe sounds straightforward, using Python if statement with arcpy.Exists and arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management, so it would be useful to see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds straightforward with ArcPy.

Use a Python if statement with arcpy.Exists and arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management.